# Django cant import my app in urls.py

Tags: python, django

I have issues importing my app in url patterns, but everything seems in place.  I get errors in *from fairy_app import views* and an error *name 'News' is not defined*

directory:

```
fairy-

  fairy-
    _init_.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py

  fairy_app-
    _init_.py
    admin.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py

  db.fairy
  manage.py
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Create your views here.

class News(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'news.html'
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from fairy_app.views import News

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'fairy.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^news/', News.as_view()),
)
```

*setting.py*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'fairy_app',
)
```

Comment: post has been edited but still no way out

Comment: If your directory listing is accurate, you have `_init_.py` instead of `__init__.py` (two underscores each side).

Answer (score 1):

In your urls.py you reference the News view without importing it. You import the views file as module.

So you can either do:

```
views.News.as_view()
```

or:

```
from fairy_app.views import News
```

2nd way is shorter but gets inconvenient if you have many view classes, so I prefer the first one.

Comment: Your way is the correct i ve made a mistake in my question by the point is that there is no way to import my app. I ve tried everything but there is no way to import my app. I get the same error in the browser (cannot import name News). BTW i am using the PyCharm IDE and i get red error line under " from fairy_app " .Its like there is no app created.

Comment: Did you add it to INSTALLED_APPS?

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem,but got sorted it out.

Create a new python file in app-level for urls
use include function in fairy-/urls file to include all other urls of the app and import views in the new file

for example;

```
#in url.py

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^greet/',include('greetings.url')),
]

#created a new file(url.py) in greetings app
#in greetings/url.py

from . import views 
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.greet),
]

#greet is the function in my views`
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I worked around it by giving the full path

```
from fairy.fairy_app.views
```

alternatively

```
from ..fairy_app.views
```